# Overwhelming majority

Tags: collocation

Is the term "overwhelming majority" popular in English? Plus, what is the difference between it and "vast majority"?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overwhelming+majority%2C+vast+majority&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coverwhelming%20majority%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvast%20majority%3B%2Cc0

Comment: (Unfortunately, Ngram does not yet pick up "yuge majority".)

Comment: Related: [Is “vast majority” something to avoid?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/126654/191178)

Comment: Roughly: a vast majority is something like 85% or more; an overwhelming majority is around 70% or more.

Comment: @Ricky  I disagree with you there.  I believe both Overwhelming and Vast are words that color a meaning far more than a degree of majority.  Overwhelmed is a word of emotion in even if used for whatever your definition of size of the majority it means (tiny majority, small majority, large majority, extremely large majority) and "vast" is a word commonly use to express a size beyond measure...vast expanses etc... that flavor the majority to feel like there was an intensity of expression or likeness on top of percentage.

Comment: @Ricky  what I'm saying is that both convey a bit of a strident statement of fact beyond an empirical observation of degree because of how those words are used in other situations.( for other readers, strident: 'Presenting a point of view, especially a controversial one, in an excessively forceful way')

Comment: Only one question per question, please. Yes, it is common. The rest is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: overwhelming majority is normal people speak; vast majority is politician speak (because they're pretentious and trying to sound sophisticated, and using "vast" here is essentially archaic, thus "sophisticated").

Answer (score 0):

As adjectives modifying *majority*, *overwhelming* and *vast* are synonymous.

From Dictionary.com, I have bolded the apt meanings:

overwhelming (adjective)

1. that overwhelms; overpowering:
   The temptation to despair may become overwhelming.

**2. so great as to render resistance or opposition useless:
an overwhelming majority.**

Vast (adjective)

1. of very great area or extent; immense:
   the vast reaches of outer space.

**2. of very great size or proportions; huge;enormous:
vast piles of rubble left in the wake of the war.**

3. very great in number, quantity, amount, etc.:
   vast sums of money.

**4. very great in degree, intensity, etc.:
an artisan of vast skill.**

Both *overwhelming majority* and *vast majority* are commonly used in the USA to mean a percentage that is much more than a *simple majority* (more than 50%). How much more than 50% is purely a matter of opinion, not part of the definition.